# Subscription model for iOS and Android PhoneGap apps

Tags: javascript, cordova, in-app-purchase, payment

We are building a PhoneGap app (both for iOS and Android) that has a subscription-based payment model and we cannot figure out which is the optimum way of doing it?

The options available we came across are:
1. UrbanAirship subscriptions. These do not not appear to support Android.
2. The [PayPal plugin for PhoneGap](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/paypal-plugin-for-phonegap-iphone/). Would Apple's approval system accept that??
3. UrbanAirship in-app purchases. Again wondering would Apple accept re-ocurring in-app purchases?

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple won't allow you use to PayPal for in app purchases. Recent comments by Marco Arment indicate Apple won't allow auto-renewing subscriptions for anything but periodical-style media purchases. I can't comment on UrbanAirship's tools.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I totally understand why Apple won't allow PayPal.. Regarding auto-renewing, what if it's a subscription that requires manual renewal? Would that be allowed only for media purchases too?

Comment: Manual renewal is fine for non-media purchases.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any ideas about Android?

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about Android. Think it depends on which app store you use. I think Google's pretty loose. Don't know about Amazon.